# Why "un film à suspense" but "une émission de divertissement" "un film d'horreur"?

Tags: prépositions, noun-phrases

I have been taught that thriller is "un film à suspense" but a horror film "un film d'horreur" and an entertainment show "une émission de divertissement". Why does "un film à suspense" need à?

My research seems to indicate de is also used with suspense.

> *Apprenons à distinguer le film de suspense du film d’horreur* ([link](https://www.horreur.quebec/apprenons-a-distinguer-le-film-de-suspense-du-film-dhorreur/))
> *Frissonnant: Histoire de Suspense et d'Horreur à la Française* ([link](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/frissonnant-alexander-ashter/1144726245))
> *La Voie: Thriller de Suspense et d'Horreur en Français* ([link](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/la-voie-roger-daevison/1144701970))
> *Des films français d'horreur et suspense* ([link](https://www.senscritique.com/liste/des_films_francais_d_horreur_et_suspense/2444789))
> *Programme TV Film de suspense* ([link](https://programmetv.ouest-france.fr/film/suspense/))

Funnily enough, directly googling "film de suspense" yields more hits than "film à suspense", including dictionary entries like [this](https://tureng.com/en/french-english/film%20de%20suspense). So why à here? Can à occur with other genres?

Comment: For the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspense/1)(a good reference) it is *à suspense*, same for [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/suspense_2), and other trustworthy dictionaries. But both are commonly used, as mentioned in [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_%C3%A0_suspense). My own opinion is that basically, suspens is not a genre (like love, horror, wester, comedy...) but an artistic device meant to hold the reader's (viewer's) attention that can be used with any genre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can work with other nouns:

> Un film à gags

> Un film à message

> Un film à *cliffhangers*

It means "with" or "mainly relying on", "mainly aiming at", as opposed to *de* that often conveys belonging to a genre.

For instance, a film could be considered *à suspense* if it relies on suspense as a main device, but at the same time not *de suspense* if it doesn't describe its genre entirely:

> Un film d'espionnage à suspense

Now, whether *film à suspense* has evolved into a set phrase to basically mean a thriller movie is also arguable.

TLFi files that use of *à* under *complément de destination* at III.D.1. [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) (*"film à suspens", "pièce à thèse"*) but you could also argue for *complément de moyen* III.D.2. or *complément d'accompagnement* III.D.3. in the case of *"à suspense"*.